# How can I use componentDidMount for tabs?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have three tabs by `react-navigation` and `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. Now I want to show some data in tabs by `json` and `componentDidMount`, But I have this error When I put `componentDidMount` in two tabs:

> null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSource')

When I use `componentDidMount` in one tab, every things is OK and working fine.

**One of my Tabs:**

```
export default class HomeTabScreen extends React.Component{

componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('men-cat.php')
    .then((response)=>response.json()).
    then((responseJson)=>{
      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2)=>r1!=r2});
      this.setState({
        isLoading:false,
        dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson)
      });
    }).done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <ListView style={{zIndex:1}}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        renderRow={ (rowData)=>

            <View style={styles.cats}>
              <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('Products' , {
                title: rowData.name,
              })}}>
                <ImageBackground source={{uri:rowData.thumb}} imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 5 }} style={styles.imgBgCats}>
                  <Text style={styles.homeCatsCostTitle}>{rowData.name}</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          }
          />
    </ScrollView>

    );
  }
}
```

**root:**

```
const MenStack = createStackNavigator({
  menStackNav: { screen: MenTabScreen,    navigationOptions:{tabBarVisible: false},
},
  Products: {
    screen: ProductsShow,
    navigationOptions:{tabBarVisible: false},
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'menStackNav',
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
});

MenStack.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
      let tabBarVisible = true;
      if(navigation.state.index > 0){
        tabBarVisible = false;
      }

      return {
        tabBarVisible,
      }
}

const HomeScreenTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:HomeTabScreen,
  },
  Women: {
    screen:WomenTabScreen,
  },
  Men: {
    screen:MenStack,
  },

},{
  tabBarOptions: {
    style:{backgroundColor:'#fff'},
    activeTintColor: '#0077FF',
    inactiveTintColor: '#0077FF60',
    indicatorStyle: {
      opacity: 0
    },
    tabStyle:{backgroundColor:'#fff',height:40,borderBottomColor:'#fff'},
    labelStyle: {
      borderBottomColor:'#fff',
        fontSize: 14,
      },
  },
    initialRouteName: 'Men',
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

Comment: Show us some code please. What heva you tried so far? Where are you getting this error?

Comment: @Vencovsky Now you can see my codes. This error is all of thing I see in console.. I think I should use `componentDidMount` for one time for all tabs, but I don't know how can I do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting happens because while your fetch is waiting for a response, the render function is trying to render a `ListView` with a non existing data source.

You can fix the problem by setting the initial value in the state to an empty datasource, or alternatively, add a check in the render function that will only render the `ListView` if the data source is not null.

```
{!!this.state.dataSource &&
 <ListView
    ...
 />}
```

Lastly, `ListView` is deprecated and has been replaced by [`FlatList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) that has a much more friendly API.

Comment: Make sure you added the condition in all the tabs.

Comment: is there any other usage of `this.state.dataSource` that isn't guarded by a condition?

Comment: Try to initialize the state with an empty datasource.